# Issue with proof: Cauchy Completeness of Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

> Having trouble understanding a cardinality-related argument when proving that all Cauchy sequences of reals numbers converge to a real limit. Came across it on *CC Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis*, [page 18](https://books.google.com/books?id=2NVJCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA18).

---

Suppose $(a_n) : n \in \Bbb N $ is a Cauchy sequence;

First the set $A = \{ x \ |\ x = a_n  \; \text{for some} \; n \in \Bbb N   \}$ is proved to be bounded and is considered to be contained in $[-M, M]$ for $M\in \Bbb N$. Then the following set is considered;

$$S = \{s \in [-M, M]  \ | \ \text{there are infinitely many $n$ in $\Bbb N$ for which $a_n \ge s $}  \}$$

The set is bounded from above and is non-empty rendering the existence of $\sup  S = b$ in $\Bbb R$. Then the author proceeds to show that $b$ is the limit to which $(a_n)$ converges.

Since $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence $\exists N \in \Bbb N$ such that $m, n \ge N \implies |a_m - a_n| \lt \frac \epsilon 2$ where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive quantity.

---

Here my issues begin..

$ (b + \frac \epsilon 2) \ \notin \ S$ since $s \ \in S \implies s \le b$. Therefore the author says **$a_n$ exceeds $(b + \frac \epsilon 2)$ only finitely often**. This apparently suggests $ \exists \ N_1(\ge N) \in \Bbb N $ such that $$ n \ge N_1 \implies a_n \lt (b + \frac \epsilon 2)  $$

This is my sketchy idea of why this is true:
There are countably infinite elements in $(a_n)$ and hence there are a similar number of elements $(a_n)$ which are less than $(b + \frac \epsilon 2)$. These must be close to each other since this is a Cauchy sequence.

But I am having trouble convincing myself in terms of a rigorous argument. Especially why $N_1 \ge N$??? Furthermore since $\exists \ s \in S$ such that $s \gt (b - \frac \epsilon 2)$ There are infinitely many $n$ for which $a_n \ge s \gt (b - \frac \epsilon 2)$. This apparently justifies the existence of $r \ge N_1$ such that $a_r \gt (b - \frac \epsilon 2)$??? How come??

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: It is easier to prove this by using the Bolzano Weierstrass thm that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. Then show that if such a subsequence converges to some b, then the whole sequence must converge to b, due to the fact that the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn Analysis. Just finishing off the Topology chapters. Haven't gotten to convergence. This was in the introductory chapter. Wanted to leave it behind, move on and come back to it because I'm fine with the completeness proof using cuts. But this proof has just been bugging me if you know what I mean..

Comment: First, it should be that $a_n$ exceeds $\mathbf{b+\epsilon/2}$ only finitely often. This is obvious from the definition of $S$ because $b+\epsilon/2\notin S$, which is true since $b=\sup S$. Second, this gives an $N_1$ such that if $n\ge N_1$ then $a_n<b+\epsilon/2$: Since $a_n\ge b+\epsilon/2$ only for finitely many values of $n$, say for $n=n_1,\dots,n_k$, let $N_1$ be larger than all of them. Third, $N_1$ could very well be less than $N$ but, luckily for us, replacing $N_1$ with anything larger still works: If all numbers $a>7$ have a property, certainly all numbers $a>50$ do as well.

Comment: Because $b$ is the least upper bound, then $b+\epsilon/2$ is a strict upper bound for $S$. So $b+\epsilon/2 \notin S$. By the definition of $S$, that means that $F=\{ n \in \mathbb{N} : a_{n} \ge b+\epsilon/2\}$ is finite or empty. If $F=\emptyset$, let $N_{1}=N$. Otherwise let $N_{1}$ be 1 greater than the maximum element of $F\cup\{N\}$. Then you're guaranteed that $n \ge N_{1}$ implies (a) $n \ge N$ and (b) $a_{n} < b+\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Andres & T.A.E. : Sorry for the typo. Thanks for pointing it out. If we choose $N_1 = Max \{ N, Max F \}$ then $n \ge N_1 \implies a_n \le b + \frac \epsilon 2$. That's clear to me now.

Comment: Actually that was flawed.. Let me try this. There are infinitely many $n$ for which $a_n$ exceeds $b - \frac \epsilon 2$. So there must exist $r$ as stated above or else $ a_n \gt b - \frac \epsilon 2 \implies n \le N_1 \implies \{ n \in \Bbb N \ | \ a_n \gt b - \frac \epsilon 2  \}$ is finite, leading to a contradiction..

Comment: T.A.E., Andres Caicedo: Thanks a lot for the input guys. Seem to have got it. Much appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of $S$, it is possible to have $s\in S$ that has an infinity of $(a_n)$ within $(s-\varepsilon,s+\varepsilon)$.  It must be shown that $S$ has at most one of these points.  If there are two elements $s_1,s_2 \in S$, then (sparing a rigorous argument) I can find arbitrarily large indexes $M$ and $N$ such that $a_M$ is arbitrarily close to $s_1$ and $a_N$ is arbitrarily close so $s_2$.  This would imply that $|a_M-a_N|$ is close to $|s_1 -s_2|$, a finite difference.  This would contradict the fact that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy.

If $b=\sup S$, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N$ with $b-\varepsilon <a_N < b$.  It also implies that there is an infinity of terms of $(a_n)$ greater than $a_{N}$.  Choose $\varepsilon = 1/k$ for $k=1,2,3...$.  Then, there is $1/k < a_k < b$ for all $k$.  Now, you can see that $a_k \rightarrow b$, and since there are no other accumulation points (last paragraph), it is the limit.